# MacOS: Internet Sharing Off / greyed out / not available on this computer

Tags: macos, sharing, internet-sharing

I've got a Mac work laptop on the latest Ventura 13.6.2.

Up until a few days ago I could use the Internet Sharing option just fine but today I noticed that the setting is greyed out. I've tried turning laptop off, reinstalling USB hub drivers, etc.,... but still just greyed out. Do you know what else I could try to have it available like before?

Comment: you say it is a `work` computer, so probably your administrator the IT person, turn it off. You will need Admin access to change it

Comment: They installed an app where we can grant ourselves admin rights for a few hours. That gets enabled fine and I can do other tasks that need admin with no problem.

It's just this screen so far that I've noticed I'm unable to use anymore (pretty sure it was fine yesterday). 

I'll reach out to the IT admins as well during their working hours, ta

Comment: Admin people are strange folks, the power of controlling others life is addictive

Comment: If you know how to use it, open Terminal app on your Mac, then enter `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist`

Comment: I don't seem to have that 'com.apple.InternetSharing.plist' file

Running the command above I get an error:
`Load failed: 5: Input/output error
Try running `launchctl bootstrap` as root for richer errors`

Trying with bootstrap or bootstrap load, I get similar errors about 'Unrecognized target specifier, did you mean... other system/com.apple...' files

Comment: sorry, forgot to tell you that command is dependent on the OS you are running, for some unknown reason to the man kind, Apple changes the location of the file

Comment: Try this `sudo launchctl start com.apple.NetworkSharing`

Comment: That seemed ok, as in 'no output' other than asking me the password and seemed successful. But the sharing screen was still off. I think that maybe what you said, just a coincidence that Admins have turned something off in their end? I'll see if they get back to me tomorrow, but wondering if they're going to know if it's not been them :S